# sql datetime issue

Tags: sql, datetime

can anyone help me, am facing some problem with the datetime function in the sql

see I have some records on the dates from 01/30/2012 to 02/21/2012 only, I need to get the datas in between these two dates, If I give 01/01/2012 as starting date and 12/01/2012 as ending date it shows all the datas correctly, but If I give 01/30/2012 as starting date and 02/21/2012 as ending date it shows only two records on 01/30/2012 and on 02/21/2012......what happened to the other records, how can I solve this problem.........thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us the SQL that is failing for you?  And maybe the data?  You haven't really given enough information for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: actually I edited some records manually, in that records I gave the value of the date column as 2012-01-30, and it took the value as 2012-01-30 00:00:00:000, and after that when I add the records from my coding the date column is stored as 2012-01-30 16:44:54.147.......I think the problem is with the time format after date......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your table structure you could do either

```
select * from your_table
where date_column between '2012-01-30' and '2012-02-12'
```

or

```
select * from your_table
where start_date >= '2012-01-30' 
and end_date <= '2012-02-12'
```

Comment: see i have 3 columns in my table...ItemName,LineTotal and CreatedDate, I need to group this records by name and date, coz I need to get the records in date wise, so I wrote the query as
SELECT        ItemName, COUNT(ItemName) AS Quantity, SUM(LineTotal) AS Amount,CONVERT(varchar(10), CreatedDate, 103) AS CreatedDate
FROM table_name
WHERE CreatedDate BETWEEN '2012-01-30' AND '2012-02-21'
GROUP BY ItemName, CONVERT(varchar(10), CreatedDate, 103) 
when I execute this query it shows only 2 records, actually I have more than 10 records within this date..how can we group the timing part next to date